# Minecraft testfor not me

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tried to make the `testfor` command in Minecraft to test for a player that is not me in a radius of 10 blocks, but when I did `/testfor @p[r=10,!name=KeithAwesome2]` it didn't work.

Please help me!

Answer (score 7):

Use `/testfor @p[r=10,name=!KeithAwesome2]`, You just had the syntax a little bit wrong.